# The double value that I defined to the variable is changing

Tags: c#, .net-core, type-conversion, double, 64-bit

I have a problem with conversation of double values.
In the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkXvT.png) Project's framework is .NET6 and i tried on .NET5 and i get same value again on x64.

Can you explain this situation to me?
And how can I get the value unchanged on x64?

Thank you.

Comment: Short: use `decimal`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when

Comment: Thank you @TimSchmelter, but I need to send this value to a service and the value type is double.

Comment: @OzanKazanç assuming "service" means web service, and that you're sending a JSON payload.. the C# decimal type will be serialized to a value the service will handle just fine.   JSON doesn't differentiate between integer, decimal and floating point.  I've seen lots of REST calls documented as taking a double value when they mean decimal.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior: floating point numbers have a limited number of significant digits, and a number that has a finite number of digits in their decimal representation may require infinite digits in their binary representation.

E.g., the decimal `0.1` is, in binary, `0.00011001100110011....` repeating. Storing this in a `float` or `double`, the number of digits is truncated.

Floating point numbers behave similar, but not identical to "real" numbers. This is something you should be aware of.

For financial mathematics, in C#, use the `decimal` type.

Here you find a good "what every developer should know" overview: https://floating-point-gui.de/.

The standard governing the most common (almost ubiquitous) implementation of floating point types is [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).